# Use QFileInfo to find creation date and time

Tags: c++, qt, qdatetime

Here's the code I have right now

```
/* Rename existing project files to .old */
if (FileIOUtil::fileExists(dest, outFileName))
{
  QFile oldFile(outFileName);
  QFileInfo fileInfo; fileInfo.setFile(oldFile);
  QDateTime created = fileInfo.lastModified();
  FileIOUtil::mvFile(dest, outFileName,
                     dest, outFileName + ".old" + created.toString());
}
```

Note: `mvfile` works like the unix command `mv`. It just moves a file to a new name.

However, this renames my `project.c` to `project.c.old.Thu Jan 1 01:00:00 1970`. I'm pretty sure the files I'm trying to rename aren't that old ;)

Any ideas why I'm getting the epoch as a result?

Comment: Your `created` calculation seems to be correct but too verbose. You can remove `oldFile` and `fileInfo` variables and use `QDateTime  created = QFileInfo(outFileName).lastModified();`. Do system utilities display last modified time of this file correctly?

Comment: @Riateche yes it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to modify the following line:

```
QFile oldFile(outFileName);
```

to

```
QFile oldFile(dest + outFileName);
```

Or as @Riateche mentioned in his comment, remove oldFile and fileInfo variables completely and do:

```
QFileInfo(dest+outFileName).created();
```

Comment: Yes, it's not surprising because if you specify non-absolute path to `QFileInfo`, it's treated as relative to the current working directory. It seems that `FileIOUtil` class prepends `dest` string internally. I didn't notice that and thought that `outFileName` is already absolute because `mvFile` works on it.